# C++ Матрица в классе

Tags: c++

Как поместить этот код в класс?

```
std::vector<std::vector<Element*>> matrix(5, std::vector<Element*>(5));
```

Чтобы в public был сам обьект а его заполнение проходило в конструкторе класса

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В классе объявляем матрицу, а инициализируем через список инициализации в конструкторе:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    std::vector<std::vector<Element*>> matrix;

    MyClass() : matrix(5, std::vector<Element*>(5)) {}
};
```